# SQLFetch return SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND on existing GUID

Tags: sql, database, guid

My class has this structure:

```
struct CommentData
{
   GUID           CommentID;
   GUID           GroupID;
   wchar_t        CreatorName[50];
   long           CreationDate;
} m_Data;
```

My constructor does the following binding:

```
void CCommentRecordset::CCommentRecordset( HDBC DBCHandle )
{
    SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, DBCHandle, &m_StmtHandle );

    static SQLLEN Len;
    SQLBindCol( m_StmtHandle, 1, SQL_C_GUID, &m_Data.CommentID, sizeof(m_Data.CommentID), &Len );
    SQLBindCol( m_StmtHandle, 2, SQL_C_GUID, &m_Data.GroupID, sizeof(m_Data.GroupID), &Len );
    SQLBindCol( m_StmtHandle, 3, SQL_C_WCHAR, m_Data.CreatorName, sizeof(m_Data.CreatorName), &Len );
    SQLBindCol( m_StmtHandle, 4, SQL_C_ULONG, &m_Data.CreationDate, 0, &Len );
}
```

My function that extracts the list of records looks like this:

```
void CCommentRecordset::GetList( CommentList& Buffer, const GUID& GroupID )
{
    Buffer.clear();

    LPOLESTR IDStr;
    StringFromCLSID( GroupID, &IDStr );

    wchar_t SQL[100];
    //   swprintf_s( SQL, _countof(SQL), L"SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE GroupID='%s'", IDStr );
    //   swprintf_s( SQL, _countof(SQL), L"SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE CreatorName='pierref'" );
    //   swprintf_s( SQL, _countof(SQL), L"SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE CommentID='{BD678ADC-A1FC-48D7-AF93-35E7D917028B}'" );
    swprintf_s( SQL, _countof(SQL), L"SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE GroupID='{F126CA9D-5AEF-479E-9172-03DF5266E6E8}'" );

    SQLRETURN Result = ::SQLExecDirect( m_StmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)SQL.c_str(), SQL_NTS );
    if ( Result == SQL_SUCCESS )
    {
        Result = SQLFetch( m_StmtHandle );
        while ( Result == SQL_SUCCESS || Result == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
        {
            Buffer.push_back( m_Data );
            Return = SQLFetch( m_StmtHandle );
        };
        SQLCloseCursor( m_StmtHandle );
    }
}
```

Now, the fun part.
If I SQLFetch using "WHERE CreatorName='pierref'", it works fine.
If I SQLFetch using "WHERE CommentID='{BD678ADC-A1FC-48D7-AF93-35E7D917028B}'", it works fine.
If I SQLFetch using "WHERE GroupID='{F126CA9D-5AEF-479E-9172-03DF5266E6E8}'", it fails with 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)

But the values returning from a fetch with CreatorName or CommentID do fill m_Data.GroupID with {F126CA9D-5AEF-479E-9172-03DF5266E6E8}.  The database itself does have the right column name (no invisible spaces before or after) and the right value.  Everything seems fine and I've been scratching my head for 90 minutes on this one.

Comment: If you hit the database directly does it show up?

Comment: @Daryl: It's an Access 2007 database (.accdb) and I couldn't find a SQL interpreter for it.  Yes, it's a temporary DB until we move to DB2 :)

Comment: Whats the data types for CommentID / GroupID within the database? I have a feeling they may be different

Comment: @Andrew: They are both Numbers of field size "Replication ID".  The only difference is that CommentID is the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at all the differences between the fields and noticed that the GroupID field is not indexed.  As far as I know, this is not a requirement for SELECT statements to work, but I indexed it just to see.  To my surprise, it now works!

I'm not an expert in databases so I fail to understand why it HAS to be indexed.  If someone can enlightened me, please do.